# Rerun VBA Formula triggered by font color change

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i wrote a simple VBA script that sums cells with a choosen font color but when i manually change a cell font color excel doesn't recalculate the formula automatically. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not reliably, no.

Comment: No, changing the format of a cell will not cause any triggers to run.  Your best bet is to make your function volatile and then any other change will cause it to recalc.

Comment: Even if you add `Application.Volatile` to your function it will not be triggered when you change a cell's font color, because that type of action doesn't trigger any recalculation of formulas.

Comment: I'd advise you to create another means, like a button or some other component, which will handle the colour update, and then you can add your action to that button too.